# Set slurm to send email after all my jobs are done?

Tags: slurm

Is it possible to do that without writing my own daemon? I know slurm can send you and email for each job, but I would like a single email when I have no more pending or running jobs.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to submit an empty job just to send the email, and ask Slurm to run that job the latest.

You can do that using the `--dependency singleton` option. From the documentation:

> singleton This job can begin execution after any previously launched
>   jobs sharing the same job name and user have terminated.

So you need to name all your jobs the same name (`--name=commonname`), and you should request the minimum resources possible to make sure that this job is not delayed further when all your other jobs are finished.